# Smoothslides.js image Preload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently using [smootheslides.js](http://kthornbloom.github.io/Smoothslides/) for the main banner on my site. However, there is this preload of the image that delays the display of the images. Not sure how I can show you the actual thing, as it's not on a live site.

Actually even on the demo site the images has a delay. Are there any way I can avoid the delay?

Answer (score 1):

I actually did this for my site yesterday. Theres not much you can do other than having fast upload speed on your server. But you can change the images to web type like png 8 bit or gif. You could also add something to the you images like so the code below however it wont change the speed...

```
<img src'FILE' style='display: none' onload='this.style.display="block";'>
```

Comment: i see... do you know whats the cause of this though? Is it the loading of images from the jquery?

Comment: It could be but very doubtful it's most likely image issues. Like size or what I already said it is possible that the plugin may be glitchy. If it is I'm not sure how to help you with that. Another cause may be the browser your using. If your using Chrome it will probably work better than firfox or ie. I have found this issue with alot of JQuery plugins in the past.

Comment: ahh.. okay alright! i managed to make it better by making the whole site lighter. thanks for your guide! :)