# Smoothslider flashes second slide briefly before slider loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The smoothslider at [this website](https://basilestudio.com) briefly flashes the second slide before the slider loads and begins animation, resulting in a jumpy/glitchy transition that isn't desirable. Based on my research, a common issue for this is failing to hide the slides, but I have .smoothslides img set to display: none, so theoretically the slider should load before showing the slides; however, that is not the case. jQuery is being called to load in my footer, before any of the smoothslides JS. I wasn't the one who initially coded this slider, so I'm having trouble getting to the bottom of the issue. Can anyone assist?
Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="smoothslides" id="myslideshow1">
     <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5d7dcf2f4aa87244f2fb32a1/t/5f1890abc9bd786bf3fed378/1595445421630/Basile-Studio-Puesto-final-comp.jpg"/>
     <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5d7dcf2f4aa87244f2fb32a1/t/5f1890a2b722c11f6a8429f4/1595445411836/Basile-Studio-Morning-Glory-comp.jpg"/>
     <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5d7dcf2f4aa87244f2fb32a1/t/5f189093854e74659bd5ed71/1595445396781/Basile-Studio-Born-and-Raised-comp.jpg"/>
     <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5d7dcf2f4aa87244f2fb32a1/t/5f189078e66d0232eba2d17c/1595445369161/Basile-Studio-Built-Box-Pendant-comp.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <img src="https://fiddle-azalea-2t8y.squarespace.com/s/banner-logo-2.png" class="logo_header"/>
   </div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
  
    $('#myslideshow1').smoothSlides({
      effectDuration: 10000,
      transitionDuration: 500,
      effect: 'zoomIn',
      navigation:false,
      pagination:false
        /* no comma on last option */
        });
  
if(jQuery("body").hasClass("homepage"))
   homepage=1;
});
```

Comment: Fix the link to 'this website' you have http:// twice

Comment: The link is now fixed - thanks for catching that :)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the full code. Can you extract the relevant parts including CSS and other JS (if any) too? And maybe put in CodePen so it's easily testable (https://codepen.io/)

Comment: looks like the slider images have not fully been loaded, that is why they "flash" - this behavior is evident on browsing in incognito/fresh cache. consider implementing a loading screen if this bothers the client/dev - take into consideration if the images have loaded

Comment: But, I have a feeling this is a problem with smoothSlides, not anything you are doing as such. Therefore, it's an issue for the smoothSlides github - whcih I see you have already initiated.

Comment: I think this will solve your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145653/smoothslides-js-image-preload

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you @sergey:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145653/smoothslides-js-image-preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145653/smoothslides-js-image-preload)